# Show Progress Dialog Storing Data to Server

Tags: android, button, post, retrofit, progressdialog

I am allowing user to create an account and then sending/storing data to server

I would like to show Progress Dialog whenever user do tap on Sign up button

Here is my code Which I am using to insert data into Database

```
private void insertUser(){

    ...

    //Creating an anonymous callback
    new Callback<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
       .......

      //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
      //Displaying the output as a toast
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    );
}
```

Code to perform button click:

```
//Overriding onclick method
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling insertUser on button click
        insertUser();
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong in it ?

Comment: You can show progress in `insertUser()` and hide it in `success()` or  `failure()`

Comment: thank you... it was really easy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare ProgressDialog dialog at class level.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
dialog.setMessage("Some message");
```

now inside insertUser() {} just do dialog.show();
now inside

```
public void success(Response result, Response response){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```